# How Can I get a right URL without query params after POST ACTION in my react js Application?

Tags: reactjs, post, react-hooks, query-string

Just when I finished my post action i have the params that i putted in my body request shown in my url. You can have a look to thesee captures [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you asked , you want to remove the params from the url after post call.

You can redirect to another link after the call ended.

If you don't change the url, the url will stay the same.